# Procedure or function has too many arguments specified in Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am very new to Azure Logic Apps. I have first time created a Logic App in which I am transforming the XML into Json and saving the json result in SQL database using Stored Proc.

When a HTTP request is received --- HTTP --- Transform XML --- Initialize xpathStatement --- Select --- For each --- Condition (if true) --- Execute Stored Procedure (v2)

where "Select" Action Parameters are:

From:

```
xpath(xml(body('HTTP')), '/*[local-name()="Envelope"]/*[local-name()="Body"]/*[local-name()="HEResponse"]/*[local-name()="HEResult"]/*[local-name()="Table"]')
```

Map: (pasting just 1st parameters function statement)

ColumnTBC

```
if(empty(xpath(item(), '/*[local-name()="Table"]/*[local-name()="ColumnTBC"]/text()')),null, xpath(item(), '/*[local-name()="Table"]/*[local-name()="ColumnTBC"]/text()')[0])
```

"Execute Stored Procedure" Action Parameters are:

1. Server Name
2. Database Name
3. Procedure Name
4. ColumnTBC

   if(empty(xpath(items('For_each'), '/*[local-name()="Table"]/*[local-name()="ColumnTBC"]/text()')),null, xpath(items('For_each'), '/*[local-name()="Table"]/*[local-name()="ColumnTBC"]/text()')[0])

I am getting below error in Stored Procedure Action (under next Failed in foreach loop):

```
{
      "status": 400,
      "message": "Procedure or function sp_Table has too many arguments specified.\r\nclientRequestId: 53203af3-8194-4c5e-b87e-c3bac11c8fe8",
      "error": {
        "message": "Procedure or function sp_Table has too many arguments specified."
      },
      "source": "sql-we.azconn-we.p.azurewebsites.net"
    }
```

Where am I making mistake in my code? And what would be a possible solution to fix this error?

Comment: In the stored procedure there is no `Eiendomsnummer ` mentioned in insert statement. Can you let us know if it works after including `Eiendomsnummer ` during insertion?

Comment: That didn´t help in fixing the error. 
Edited the posted question with modified Stored Proc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stored procedure only accepts one parameter, it looks like you were changing from parsing the json in the stored procedure and the logic app and you now have a mixture that doesn't match up.

```
create procedure [dbo].[sp_Table]
(
    @json varchar(max)
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
Then do I need to remove the parameters from "Execute Stored Procedure" Action in Logic App ?
How do I pass @json to "Execute Stored Procedure" Action ?

Comment: I would add a new Execute Stored Procedure step in the Logic App because it should read the proper parms from the database so you can just pass the json to it.